# Storing large numbers for RSA encryption in java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, storing-data

Before I post my code, I think it is best that I layout a couple of things first.

**Goal:**

Perform very basic RSA encryption on a couple of small numbers. For those of you who are familiar with RSA encryption, I have posted the values being used for the algorithm below.

**Current RSA numbers/values:**

P=29

Q=31

N=P*Q

Phi=((P-1)*(Q-1))

E=11

**My issue:**

The problem arises when I am trying to decrypt my code. The encryption works as designed.

**Code:**

```
long[] mesg = new long[]{8, 7, 26, 28};
long[] encrypted_mesg = new long[mesg.length];

for(int i=0; i<mesg.length; i++){
  encrypted_mesg[i]=(long)((Math.pow(mesg[i],E))%N);
  System.out.print(encrypted_mesg[i] + " ");
}
System.out.println();

//Decrpyt (not functioning-long to small, Big Integer not working)
for(int j=0; j<encryp_mesg.length; j++){
  BigInteger decrypt = new BigInteger(Math.pow(encryp_mesg[j],D) + "");
  System.out.print(decrypt.toString() + " ");
}
```

The initial problem was the fact that D (private exponent), when applied as an exponent, was way to big for long. I did a quick Google search and decided to try and implement BigInteger. When I run the program, it throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Infinity"

at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)

at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:461)
at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:597)
at RSA_Riddles.main(RSA_Riddles.java:23)**
```

**What I have tried to fix the problem:**

To be honest, I have not tried really anything because I know the answer does not compute to infinity, but BigInteger thinks that it does. Is there anyway that I can store a number such as 130^611? If so, How?

**Big Question:**

How can I store the values needed to perform the decryption?

*Thank you in advance to any who try and help me!*

Comment: I don't know if it's design or luck you test only values up to 28 when your encryption calculation produces the wrong result for most values from 29 up Also the decryption sihould similarly be mod n: m = c^d mod n. Also doing exponentiate and modulo separately is barely practical for your toy size, but doing it for secure sizes would take hugely longer than your lifetime (or your computer's), so actual implementations interleave them as explained in Wikipedia among others -- and then for toy size you don't need bignums at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is occurring because you are doing the calculations with primitive data types, then storing those primitives in a BigInteger. This defeats the purpose of using a BigInteger. Let's look at the offending line:

```
BigInteger decrypt = new BigInteger(Math.pow(encryp_mesg[j],D) + "");
```

When Java evaluates this line, it will first take this expression

```
Math.pow(encryp_mesg[j],D) + ""
```

And evaluate it. It will then pass the result of this evaluation to the constructor of BigInteger. However, at this point you have already exceeded the bounds of the data types you're working with. Instead, you should be doing the math with BigIntegers, like this:

```
BigInteger e = new BigInteger(Integer.toString(encryp_mesg[j]));
BigInteger decrypt  = e.pow(D);
```

Now you're only doing calculations using BigInteger, and only storing in primitive data types values that you already had stored in primitive data types.

Comment: Thank you, I will change the implementation immediately. Also, does BigInteger have any limits? If so, what are they?

Comment: Glad I could help! If it works for you, it'd be great if you could follow SO etiquette and accept the answer

BigIntegers are 'arbitrary precision', meaning that they support as large a number as your machine has resources for (You're unlikely to run up against that limit)

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob to SO. This was my first question. How do I accept the answer?

Comment: Should be a grey check mark to the left of my answer - click that and it turns green - thanks!

Comment: I am on my windows phone and the check does not appear. I will check it when I return home.

Comment: There is still one other problem, how do I use the "e.pow(D"). Since D is a long, I can not use the .pow() function to perform this math.

Comment: @jpgamer31 First perform the conversion to `BigInteger` using `BigInteger.valueOf`. You may want to check out `BigInteger#modPow` method too. Finally, `BigInteger` values are basically bound by implementation and memory. Basically: don't worry, unless you're trying to do stupid things such as performing exponentiation of large numbers without modulus.