# Wrong result with the decryption formula in RSA algorithm using Arraylist in java

Tags: java, algorithm, rsa

I'm trying to solve the problem with the decryption in RSA algorithm.

```
  ArrayList<Integer> m=convertTextToInt(str,e,n,listc);

  for (int elem1 : m){
  System.out.print( elem1+ " "); 

}
```

Here, I'm passing str which is a string from user it will converted to integer numbers in the convertTextToInt method, a number e and n to calculate the cipher text and array list to store the value after calculate the cipher text with the formula

```
   int c= (int)(Math.pow(Coded,e))%n;
       listc.add(c);
```

then i write this in the main, the problem is that whenever i executed this loop it gives the same result which is 144 !!:

```
System.out.print("plain text is: ");
for (int element : m){
int plain = (int)(Math.pow(element,d))%n;
listp.add(plain);

System.out.print("listp:"+listp);
  }
```

i tried to change the datatype for the plain to double and it gives me another number but not the right number.

my question is :  why the formula of the plain text (description) gives me the same and wrong result every time which is 144 ! :(

Comment: The "deception" algorithm is only wrong if it fails to [*deceive*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deceive) you, aka mislead, dupe, fool, trick, ...

Comment: Please, clarify your question. I am voting to close

Comment: I mean decryption** sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Near dupe [Storing large numbers for RSA encryption in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536018/storing-large-numbers-for-rsa-encryption-in-java)

You don't give any clue what numbers you are using, but RSA is only secure if you use numbers of at least about 1000 bits (about 330 decimal digits) which absolutely requires `BigInteger` in Java. Even this is borderline unsafe; current security *standards* like those for the WWW from CA/browser forum and for the US government from NIST require 2048 bits.

Even for 'toy' numbers (often used in coursework where no actual security is desired) that fit in Java `int` (9+ decimal digits) or `long` (18+ digits), the notional 'raw' decryption computation c<sup>d</sup> does NOT fit. `Math.pow` is floating-point so it first returns an imprecise (rounded-off) result, and truncating to `int` or `long` turns that into a completely wrong and useless result. You should instead do modular exponentiation in stages with *each stage* modulo n, [as explained in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) linked from the [article on RSA](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Decrypting_messages).
If you use `BigInteger` (as you must for non-toy cases) its `modPow` method already does this.

Also note 'textbook' RSA -- only exponentiation modulo a large semiprime -- is not actually secure in practice. This is also explained briefly in that Wikipedia article, and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ has dozens of Q&As on the dangers and limitations of textbook RSA and what to do instead. If you actually want security in Java, at least 'desktop' or 'phone' Java (like Android, but not smartcards and embedded devices), the Java Cryptography Extensions already implement RSA correctly, *including* the additional things you need such as PKCS1 padding.

Comment: Thank you so much this is very helpful! I used  `  BigInteger `   and it's working now! Thank you so much!